# Read contents and attachements from emails sent from a particular emailid

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, email, email-attachments

Is there a way to develop a widows form/web application using C# .net that can read contents of emails sent from a particular email ID? Attachments will be text files and I have the code to read through text file. But I need to know how to parse the emails body, extract text file etc . Please provide code/reference links if you have any.

Comment: When you retrieve mail from server what kind of data do you receive ? Is it mime ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var messages = MailMessageQueue.ToList<MailMessage>(); //Define your MailMessageQueue
foreach (var message in messages)
{

   foreach (var attachment in message.Attachements)
   {
      var path = Path.GetFullPath(attachment.Name);
      //You can use StreamReader in order to parse
     ...... 
   }
}
```